# Android - OneSignal callback methods never fired(notificationReceived - notificationOpened)

Tags: android, callback, onesignal

I'm using onesignal to push notification and it works fine but i faced an issue with "Receiving Notifications" since i want to take an action when receive the notification.

here's my code, i follow the documentation but i got nothing. where's the issue?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
static Context context;
@Override public void onCreate() { 
  super.onCreate(); 
  context = getApplicationContext();


OneSignal.startInit(this) 
 .autoPromptLocation(true) 
 .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())   
 .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
 .init(); 
}

private class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {

@Override
public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "notificationReceived!!!!!!");

}
}

  private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {

@Override
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult openedResult) {
    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "notificationOpened!!!!!!");

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`NotificationReceivedHandler`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationreceivedhandler-) will only fire if your app is in the foreground.

If you need to take action on a received notification regardless of your app's state you will need to setup a OneSingal [`NotificationExtenderService`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationextenderservice-) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from the documentation

> By default OneSignal will open or resume your launcher Activity when a notification is tapped on. You can disable this behavior by adding the meta-data tag com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT set to DISABLE inside your application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

[see for yourself](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations)

Comment: thank you for your answer but you didn't get my issue. I want fire "notificationReceived" once device receive notification as it dose not fire except when app completely close(from background). any suggestions appreciated.